# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to find for which values of $a \in \Bbb N, a \ne 0$ the following limit exists and it is finite:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\right)}{x^2}  $$

Applying L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\sim \frac{\sin (ax) \cdot a}{2x}\sim \frac{a^2}{2}$$
Then $$ \frac{\cos (\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2})}{x^2}  \sim   \frac{\cos (\pi \cdot \frac{a^2}{2})}{x^2}.$$
$$\cos (\pi \cdot \frac{a^2}{2})=0 \implies a^2=1+2k, \quad k \in \Bbb N$$
and in this case the limit is $0$.

In the book the suggested solution is $a^2=1+2k$ for which the limit is $$ \frac{(-1)^k \cdot (2k+1)^2\cdot\pi}{24}$$

but I don't understand this solution.

Trying to solve the limit with $a^2=1+2k$:

$$ \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} \sim \frac{-\sin (\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos ax}{x^2}) \cdot \pi \cdot  \frac{\sin (ax)  a  x^2 - (1-\cos (ax))  2x}{x^4}}{2x} $$$$ =  \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2}+k \pi\right) \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{(1-\cos(ax))2- \sin(ax) ax}{2 \cdot x^4}$$$$= (-1)^k \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{(1-\cos(ax))2- \sin(ax) ax}{2 \cdot x^4} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of what you wrote is incorrect:
$$\frac{\cos (\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2})}{x^2}  \sim   \frac{\cos (\pi \cdot \frac{a^2}{2})}{x^2}$$

You're taking the limit of the top of the fraction, but not the bottom. Instead, you need to consider under what circumstances the limit of the entire fraction might exist. Of course, this can only happen if the top tends towards zero, i.e. if
$$\cos (\pi \cdot \frac{a^2}{2}) = 0$$

So the limit might exist if $a^2 = 1 + 2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$. Next, assuming $a$ is one of these values, compute the limit of the entire fraction using L'Hospital's rule:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} \space \cos \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\right)}{\frac{d}{dx} x^2} $$

$$ = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\pi \left(\frac{a\sin(ax)x - 2(1 - \cos(ax))}{x^3}\right)\sin(\pi\cdot\frac{1 - \cos(ax)}{x^2})}{2x}
$$

$$
= \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\pi\cdot(a \sin(ax) x - 2\cdot(1 - \cos(ax)))}{2x^4} \right) \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \sin\left(\pi \frac{1 - \cos(ax)}{x^2}\right) \right)
$$

You already know the second limit is $\sin\left(\pi\cdot\frac{a^2}{2}\right) = \pm 1$ (depending on the particular value of $a$). The first limit is straightforward. Just apply L'Hospital's Rule repeatedly until you have your answer.

Comment: in the post I've added a temptative to solve the limit  but I can't see how to have the right solution.

Comment: @Anne You cannot get rid of the $x$'s in the top part of the fraction as you are doing. You have to use L'Hospital's rule on the entire _original_ expression. It tells you that the limit is equal to the limit of $(\frac{d}{dx} \cos(\pi \cdot (1-\cos(ax))/x^2) / (2x)$

Comment: could you explain how you solve the limit in your answer? I'm trying to solve it with l'hopital but I have some doubts in any case

Comment: @Anne I added some more details. The solution was a bit more involved than I thought at first...

Comment: you didn't put a factor 2 in the third passage

Comment: Thanks @Anne. I believe all typos are fixed now

Comment: thanks to you for your help, I solved the limit!

Answer (score 3):

Using l'Hôpital in this case is not the best strategy. You have
$$
\cos(ax)=1-\frac{a^2x^2}{2}+\frac{a^4x^4}{24}+o(x^4)
$$
and therefore
$$
\pi\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}=\pi\frac{a^2}{2}-\pi\frac{a^4x^2}{24}+o(x^2)
$$
In order for the limit to be finite, we need that
$$
\frac{a^2\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi
$$
for some integer $k$, so $a^2=1+2k$. Now the numerator is
$$
\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi-\frac{a^4\pi x^2}{24}+o(x^2)\Bigr)=
(-1)^k\sin\Bigl(\frac{a^4\pi x^2}{24}+o(x^2)\Bigr)=
(-1)^k\frac{a^4\pi x^2}{24}+o(x^2)
$$
and therefore the limit is
$$
(-1)^k\frac{(2k+1)^2\pi}{24}
$$
Obviously $k$ should be a nonnegative integer.

Comment: Agreed, this is much more straightforward than my solution

Comment: @AlexG. Let's always thank Landau for this gift!

Answer (score 0):

Although a solution is provided (and was accepted) I wanted provide a solution using Maclaurin series of cos:

$$
cos(x)=1-x^2/2!-x^4/4!+x^6/6!-...
\\ cos(ax) = 1-a^2x^2/2!-a^4x^4/4!+a^6x^6/6!-...
\\ 1-cos(ax) = a^2x^2/2!+a^4x^4/4!-a^6x^6/6!+...
\\ \frac{(1-cos(ax)}{x^2} = a^2/2!+a^4x^2/4!-a^6x^4/6!+... 
\\ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot \frac{1-\cos (ax)}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot (a^2/2!+a^4x^2/4!-a^6x^4/6!+... ) \right)}{x^2} 
$$

Since the denominator in $\lim_{x\to 0}$ goes to zero, in order for the limit exist, the numerator also should go to zero for $\lim_{x\to 0}$:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} {\cos \left(\pi \cdot (a^2/2!+a^4x^2/4!-a^6x^4/6!+... ) \right)} = \lim_{x\to 0} {\cos \left(\pi \cdot a^2/2 \right)}
$$

for ${\cos \left(\pi \cdot a^2/2 \right)}$ to be zero $a^2$ should be $1+2k$

In this case we can apply the L'Hospital's Rule:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos \left(\pi \cdot (a^2/2!+a^4x^2/4!-a^6x^4/6!+... ) \right)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\sin \left(\pi \cdot (a^2/2!+a^4x^2/4!-a^6x^4/6!+... ) \right)(\pi (a^4(2x)/4!-4a^6x^3/6!+... ))}{2x}
= {-\sin \left(\pi \cdot a^2/2 \right)\pi a^4/4!} = \pm \pi a^4/24
$$

for which it is positive if k is even, and it is negative if k is odd.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that $$\dfrac{1-\cos ax} {x^2}\to\dfrac{2k+1}{2}$$ so that the limit in question exists. This clearly means that $a\neq 0$ and further $$a^2=2k+1$$ and thus $k\geq 0$.

Now we can write expression in question as $$(-1)^k\cdot\dfrac {\sin\left(\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\left(1-\dfrac{2}{2k+1}\cdot \dfrac{1-\cos ax}{x^2}\right)\right)}{x^2}$$ which can be written as $(-1)^{k}(\sin f(x)) /x^2$ where $f(x) \to 0$. And we rewrite it as $$(-1)^k\cdot \frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)} \cdot\frac{f(x)} {x^2}$$ Thus the desired limit equals the limit of $$(-1)^k\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{2k+1}\cdot\frac{1-\cos ax} {x^2}\right)=(-1)^k\cdot \frac{\pi} {2}\frac{a^2x^2-4\sin^2(ax/2)}{x^4}$$ Putting $ax=2t$ we can see that the above equals $$(-1)^k\frac{a^{4}\pi}{8}\frac{t^2-\sin^2t}{t^4}$$ You can easily check via factoring that last factor tends to $1/3$ and hence the desired limit is $$(-1)^k\cdot\frac{(2k+1)^2\pi}{24}$$